# How do you perform a CASE SENSITIVE nested REPLACE command?

Tags: sql, replace, nested, case-sensitive

I have a table:

```
Building                                        Building
1__bEast                                        1 East
1__bSouth                                       1 South
500__bBldg__d                                   500 Bldg.
501__bBldg__d                                   501 Bldg.
B__u1                                           B-1
B__u2                                           B-2
B__u2__bWest                                    B-2 West
Building__b10__b__PBldg__bTen__p                Building 10 (Bldg Ten)
D__7T__b__PDiagnostic__b__7__bTreatment__p      D & T (Diagnostic & Treatment)
n__fa                                           n/a
```

The list on the left shows the actual table.  The list on the right is how I want them to appear in the results.  In order for me to do this, I am using the following nested REPLACE command:

```
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(Building,'__P','(')
                ,'__p',')')
            ,'__b',' ')
        ,'__u','-')
    ,'__7','&')
,'__d','.') as [Building]
```

The problem with this is that the "__P" and "__p" are treated the same and the results end up like this:

```
Building 10 (Bldg Ten(
D & T (Diagnostic & Treatment(
```

The right parentheses ")" do not show up.

I tried using:

```
...REPLACE(REPLACE(Building COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,'__P','('),'__p',')')...
```

but it doesn't seem to work in a nested REPLACE query.  I get basically the same results.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure there's not a function in the code that does the encoding/decoding for these values already?  It's very suspicious to me that all the special characters have been altered to different values and so consistently.  Perhaps you just need to call a function of sorts which already does this type of replacement.

Comment: Why would you use a case-insensitive collation if you want a case-sensitive replace?

Comment: @xQbert - There probably is code that does encoding/decoding..but i have no idea where to look or how to use that code.  and i don't know why the values are entered this way.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I didn't realize i was using case-insensitive collation.

Comment: I would encourage you to look at your API library or system tables to find where others referenced this field to see how they handled this unique encoding scheme.  I suspect it was originally done to resolve some data storage or display challenges involving special characters.  Other code within the system must have dealt with this in the past find a prior example and see how it manages this data.  It may be embedded in a report somewhere which calls a function to display these values or on a screen which displays these values for maintenance. Inventing your own without understanding is risky.

Comment: @Sung . . . "CI" --> "case insensitive; "CS" -- "case sensitive".  An (admittedly) awful way of getting case sensitivity into string functions, but that is how the folks at SQL Server decided to do it.

Comment: @xQbert - thanks for the info. I will take you advice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I just realized that from lad2025's suggestion.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` (case sensitive):

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(Building VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab
SELECT '1__bEast'                                     
UNION ALL SELECT '1__bSouth'                                       
UNION ALL SELECT '500__bBldg__d'                                  
UNION ALL SELECT '501__bBldg__d'                                   
UNION ALL SELECT 'B__u1'                                           
UNION ALL SELECT 'B__u2'                                           
UNION ALL SELECT 'B__u2__bWest'                                    
UNION ALL SELECT 'Building__b10__b__PBldg__bTen__p'              
UNION ALL SELECT 'D__7T__b__PDiagnostic__b__7__bTreatment__p'      
UNION ALL SELECT 'n__fa';

SELECT Building,
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(Building COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS ,'__P','(')
                ,'__p',')')
            ,'__b',' ')
        ,'__u','-')
    ,'__7','&')
,'__d','.') as [Building] 
FROM #tab
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/386481)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════╗
║                  Buidling                  ║           Replaced           ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║ 1__bEast                                   ║ 1 East                       ║
║ 1__bSouth                                  ║ 1 South                      ║
║ 500__bBldg__d                              ║ 500 Bldg.                    ║
║ 501__bBldg__d                              ║ 501 Bldg.                    ║
║ B__u1                                      ║ B-1                          ║
║ B__u2                                      ║ B-2                          ║
║ B__u2__bWest                               ║ B-2 West                     ║
║ Building__b10__b__PBldg__bTen__p           ║ Building 10 (Bldg Ten)       ║
║ D__7T__b__PDiagnostic__b__7__bTreatment__p ║ D&T (Diagnostic & Treatment) ║
║ n__fa                                      ║ n__fa                        ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════╝
```

Add also one more `REPLACE(..., 'n__fa', 'n/a')` or `REPLACE(..., '__f', '/')` depending on your needs.

Comment: Wow...so simple.  I feel dumb.   Thanks lad2025!!